# Scala Spark App submitted to yarn-cluster and unregistered with SUCCEEDED without doing anything

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

## Goal

Run our scala spark app jar on yarn-cluster mode. It works with standalone cluster mode and with yarn-client, but for some reason it does not run to completion for yarn-cluster mode.

## Details

The last portion of the code it seems to execute is on assigning the initial value to the Dataframe when reading the input file. It looks like it does not do anything after that. None of the logs look abnormal and there are no Warns or errors either. It suddenly gets unregistered with status succeeded and everything gets killed. On any other deployment mode (eg. yarn-client, standalone cluster mode) everything runs smoothly to completion.

```
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with SUCCEEDED
```

I have also ran this job on spark 1.3.x and 1.4.x on a vanilla spark/YARN cluster and a cdh 5.4.3 cluster as well. All with the same results. What could possibly be the issue?

Job was run with the command below and the input file is accessible through hdfs.

```
bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --class AssocApp ../associationRulesScala/target/scala-2.10/AssociationRule_2.10.4-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar hdfs://sparkMaster-hk:9000/user/root/BreastCancer.csv
```

## Code snippets

this is the code in the area were the dataframe is loaded. It spits out the log message "Uploading Dataframe..." but there is nothing else after that. Refer to the driver's logs below

```
//...
  logger.info("Uploading Dataframe from %s".format(filename))
  sparkParams.sqlContext.csvFile(filename)

  MDC.put("jobID",jobID.takeRight(3))
  logger.info("Extracting Unique Vals from each of %d columns...".format(frame.columns.length))
  private val uniqueVals = frame.columns.zipWithIndex.map(colname => (colname._2, colname._1, frame.select(colname._1).distinct.cache)).
//...
```

### Driver logs

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/filecache/60/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/07/22 15:56:52 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
15/07/22 15:56:54 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_1434116948302_0097_000001
15/07/22 15:56:55 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
15/07/22 15:56:55 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
15/07/22 15:56:55 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
15/07/22 15:56:55 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Starting the user application in a separate Thread
15/07/22 15:56:55 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization
15/07/22 15:56:55 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization ... 
15/07/22 15:56:56 INFO AssocApp$: Starting new Association Rules calculation. From File: hdfs://sparkMaster-hk:9000/user/root/BreastCancer.csv
15/07/22 15:56:56 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: SUCCEEDED, exitCode: 0
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO associationRules.primaryPackageSpark: Uploading Dataframe from hdfs://sparkMaster-hk:9000/user/root/BreastCancer.csv 
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.0
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@119.81.232.13:41459]
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 41459.
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1434116948302_0097/blockmgr-f0e66040-1fdb-4a05-87e1-160194829f84
15/07/22 15:56:57 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 267.3 MB
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1434116948302_0097/httpd-79b304a1-3cf4-4951-9e22-bbdfac435824
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:36021
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 36021.
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:53274
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 53274.
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://119.XX.XXX.XX:53274
15/07/22 15:56:58 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Created YarnClusterScheduler
15/07/22 15:56:59 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 34498.
15/07/22 15:56:59 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 34498
15/07/22 15:56:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/07/22 15:56:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 119.81.232.13:34498 with 267.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 119.81.232.13, 34498)
15/07/22 15:56:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/07/22 15:56:59 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/YarnAM#-819146876])
15/07/22 15:56:59 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at sparkMaster-hk/119.81.232.24:8030
15/07/22 15:56:59 INFO yarn.YarnRMClient: Registering the ApplicationMaster
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 2 executor containers, each with 1 cores and 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container request (host: Any, capability: <memory:1408, vCores:1>)
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container request (host: Any, capability: <memory:1408, vCores:1>)
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Started progress reporter thread - sleep time : 5000
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with SUCCEEDED
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory .sparkStaging/application_1434116948302_0097
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO util.Utils: Shutdown hook called
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO util.Utils: Deleting directory /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1434116948302_0097/httpd-79b304a1-3cf4-4951-9e22-bbdfac435824
15/07/22 15:57:00 INFO util.Utils: Deleting directory /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1434116948302_0097/userFiles-e01b4dd2-681c-4108-aec6-879774652c7a
```

Comment: did you get the solution to your problem? I get similar behaviour with Spark 1.6.1.

Comment: What happens to data is not clear. What is the action here?